# the possible solution to this design issue?

Tags: html

I need to know how to fix this issue in the designs of forms..
Getting this in [firefox](http://img409.imageshack.us/img409/8005/78624010.jpg)

and this in [IE](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5359/36461096.jpg)...

the color is not an issue.. juz need the alignment to be fixed...

The code goes like this :

```
<div class="content_form_box7_main">
<div class="content_form_box7_main1">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Comments" class="content_form_box7_inside"/>
</div>
</div>
```

the style goes like :

```
.content_form_box7_main{
    float:left; 
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    padding:5px 0px 2px 0px; 
    width:281px;
}
.content_form_box7_main1{
    float:left; 
    padding:0px 0px 0px 40px;
}
.content_form_box7_inside{
    float:left; 
    background-image:url(images/amcro_contact4.gif); 
    width:206px; 
    height:43px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    border:none; 
    background-color:#E0D1B4; vertical-align:top;
}
```

apologies if it looks complex ...

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the underlying HTML.

Comment: Add padding to input elements

Comment: @ Pekka and @ thisMayhem... please have a look at the html....

Answer (score 0):

What does your CSS look like?
Have you tried adding the following to the input elements?:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

or

```
vertical-align: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align style in input tag is browser dependent. My advice will get over it. 
Remove height value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to the input elements.